# Find the 2nd ip address per line on file

Tags: bash

How can I find the 2nd ip address per line?

Input

```
hostname1,10.160.226.49,10.160.35.80,10.14.1.80,10.14.5.80,10.160.0.27, 2048
hostname2,10.160.235.89,10.160.35.81,10.14.1.81,10.14.5.81,10.157.233.144, 1024
hostname3,10.160.231.247,10.160.35.82,10.14.1.82,10.14.5.82,10.157.239.26, 512
hostname4,10.160.227.232,10.160.35.84,10.14.1.84,10.14.5.84,10.241.14.2, 2048
hostname5,10.160.224.218,10.160.35.85,10.14.1.85,10.14.5.85,10.157.234.82, 1024
```

Output

```
10.160.35.80
10.160.35.81
10.160.35.82
10.160.35.83
10.160.35.84
10.160.35.85
```

Comment: Have you tried something? This can be done very easily using `awk` or `cut`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
cut -d "," -f 3 file
```

or with GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '^[^,]*,[^,]*,\K[^,]*' file
```

or with awk:

```
awk -F "," '{print $3}' file
```

or with bash's builtin commands:

```
while IFS="," read -r a b c d; do echo "$c"; done < file
```

or with an array:

```
while IFS="," read -ra a; do echo "${a[2]}"; done < file
```

Output:

```
10.160.35.80
10.160.35.81
10.160.35.82
10.160.35.84
10.160.35.85
```